# I have a query that selects the sum of certain data at time intervals, how do I also get the total for these intervals?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

This query produces 3 sums per time interval:

```
select 
    "interval", 
    SUM("mv"."bought") as "amount_bought", 
    SUM("mv"."sold") as "amount_sold", 
    SUM("mv"."transferred") as "amount_transferred" 
from "mv_24hr_hourly_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers" as "mv" 
inner join (
    select "contract_address" 
    from "addresses" 
    where not exists (
        select 1 
        from "address_tags" 
        where "address" = "addresses"."contract_address" and "tag_id" = ?
    ) 
    order by "supply_percentage" desc
) as "ca" 
on "ca"."contract_address" = "mv"."contract_address" 
group by "interval" 
order by "interval" desc'
```

How can I also produce those 3 sums over every row, aka no time interval?

Example current output:

```
      interval       | amount_bought       | amount_sold       | amount_transferred 
---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------------
 2021-05-07 22:00:00 |                   0 |                 0 |                        0
 2021-05-07 21:00:00 |                   0 |                 0 |                        0
 2021-05-07 20:00:00 |                   0 |                 0 |                        0
 2021-05-07 19:00:00 |                   0 |                 0 |                        0
 2021-05-07 18:00:00 |                   0 |                 0 |                        0
 2021-05-07 17:00:00 |                   0 |                 0 |                        0
```

I am looking for the total bought, total sold and total transferred over every row, in addition to the current data I collect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `grouping sets` is the specific answer to the question, your query should be rewritten:

```
select "interval", 
       SUM(mv."bought") as amount_bought, 
       SUM(mv."sold") as amount_sold, 
       SUM(mv."transferred") as amount_transferred 
from "mv_24hr_hourly_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers" mv join
     "addresses" a
     on a."contract_address" = mv."contract_address" 
where not exists (
        select 1 
        from "address_tags" at
        where at."address" = a."contract_address" and at."tag_id" = ?
    ) 
group by grouping sets ( ("interval"), () )
order by "interval" desc nulls last;
```

Notes:

- You should really dispense with the escaped identifiers.  They just make the query harder to read and write.
- Don't use SQL keywords such as `interval` as an identifier.
- Qualify *all* column references.  You should give all tables aliases as well to simplify this.
- The subquery is unnecessary.
- The `order by` in the subquery is not only unnecessary but is ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your tips, as someone fairly new to writing anything more than a simple query this was really helpful and your answer worked as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can try to use GROUPING_SETS
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-grouping-sets/

Comment: Could you explain how grouping sets would help me here? Thanks